# Decorator works for Function but not Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-decorators

Need a bit of help correcting a decorator for unittest. I'm not sure how to meet the requirements of unit test.  **The idea of this decorator is to mark the test as an expectedFailure IF True is passed in.  Otherwise allow the test to simply run.**  This decorator works for test functions but doesn't work for class definitions

```
import unittest

def expectedFailureIf(expFailure):
    if expFailure: 
        return unittest.expectedFailure
    return lambda func: func

@expectedFailureIf(GetCurrentOS() == kPlatMac)  # Fails on Class
class someClass(unittest.TestCase):
    #@expectedFailureIf(GetCurrentOS() == kPlatMac) # Works on Function
    def test_sometestA(self):
        assert True

    def test_sometestB(self):
        assert False
```

The error that I'm getting is test_sometest() takes exactly 1 argument.  Removing the decorator allows the test to run.  Moving the decorator to top of function allows the test to run.

History... One of my platforms works fine and the other platform does not.  I want to allow one platform to run all the tests while the other platform will be marked as expected failures.  Of course I do not want to use skip or skip if.  Since that won't allow the valid platform to run.  Marking them as expected failure will also not work since one platform will return unexpected success.  With the expectedFailureIf() in place each platform will correctly report and once things are fixed these tests will report as unexpected success.  Which will notify ME when things are fixed.  For me... this seems a better outcome.

Comment: You don't need to use `== True`. It's not the reason you have an issue, but it's all you need to do. Your decorator is otherwise exactly the same as the [one used by Python's own test suite](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/support/__init__.py#L187-L195).

Comment: @wim: skipping is *not the same thing* as expecting failure. Skipping means you don't run the test. Expecting failure runs the test then asserts that the test fails (reporting on unexpected success).

Comment: SkipIf may have the same functionality but it isn't the same.  I want the tests to be run on both platforms.  I want to be notified when fixed on the currently failing platform.  Also, I have ideas for other decorators for unittest which will give me better tracking of things that 'should' be fixed.  UnitTest decorators are a bit limiting.  So this is something I want to learn.

Comment: OK, I understand it now.  You want there to be a test failure when it's fixed and the test unexpectedly passes on that platform.  Quite convoluted, but makes sense now.

Comment: @wim: and the `skipIf()` conditional decorator does the exact same thing as this decorator does, so if the OP has a problem with this decorator then `skipIf` is a problem too.

Comment: Your problem must be elsewhere, because the decorator appears to be fine. The sample test you posted is *not* fine, however, as it inherits from a module (`unittest`), not a class, and the syntax is invalid. Can you please provide us with a [mcve] that we can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have updated the code.  It was originally intended as sudo code not a full example.  Posted for discussion.  The sample code now works.  The desired behavior was originally included and is now bolded.  I think I'm missing something about the definitions of decorators when used with Classes.  That the decorator maybe required to be defined differently.  Not sure how to make it work for both Functions and Classes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  The code you linked from CPython master branch and said is "used by Python's own test suite" was added in [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2496f331a75c9dd30ef8588ae86179131227163a). [The related issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue12958) was resolved in Python 3.3, Python 3.4. Your comments are invalid since this is a Python 2.7 question.  You wrote "the decorator appears to be fine" but did you actually try it on 2.7?  Because it doesn't work!

Comment: @wim: right, I should have checked the `expectedFailure` decorator on 2.7. The decorator the OP posted works fine, it is the `unittest.expectedFailure` that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

On Python 3 your code is working fine.  The [implementation of `unittest.expectedFailure`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d2cbfffc842b00b5257aa1c25dbcdeb456b6a249/Lib/unittest/case.py#L119-L121) is better there, and it works correctly when decorating on either classes or functions.

On Python 2, the [`unittest.expectedFailure` is only designed to work on functions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/468f97b4640e69b237a707a0ef9152d1c023f701/Lib/unittest/case.py#L87-L95).

Here's a replacement which works on Python 2.

```
import inspect
import types
import unittest

def expectedFailureIf(condition):
    if callable(condition):
        condition = condition()
    if not condition:
        # return identity function for no-op
        return lambda x: x
    def patch(func_or_class):
        if isinstance(func_or_class, types.FunctionType):
            return unittest.expectedFailure(func_or_class)
        for name, member in inspect.getmembers(func_or_class):
            if name.startswith('test') and isinstance(member, types.MethodType):
                setattr(func_or_class, name, unittest.expectedFailure(member))
        return func_or_class
    return patch

@expectedFailureIf(True)
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_that_passes(self):
        assert 2 + 2 == 4

    def test_that_fails(self):
        assert 2 + 2 == 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Result:

```
test_that_fails (__main__.MyTest) ... expected failure
test_that_passes (__main__.MyTest) ... unexpected success

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK (expected failures=1, unexpected successes=1)
```

### Warning!

The fact that an unexpected success doesn't fail the test run is a bug in Python! It was addressed back in Jan 2014 (Python 3.4), but this bugfix was not merged into 2.7's branch due to backwards compatibility concerns (see the comments on [issue20165](https://bugs.python.org/issue20165)).  So, that's now a Python 2 ["feature"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt3Mk.jpg), unfortunately.

If this is a deal-breaker to you, consider upgrading to a more [recent Python version](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and/or using a [better test runner](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Are you in Python 3.x or 2.7?  All I get with your code is:

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Comment: If the test is run the test should return "test_some_test (__main__.SomeClassTest) ... expected failure." Just before the dashed and Status report.  So the test did not run.  Modified your code to include print 'Marked' just below the If condition:  and swapped out assert with math to assert False.  Ran the tests and found that the decorator is being called and being marked.  Unfortunately the test itself is NOT being run.

Comment: Wrong, the test is being run.  Put a print statement in or something to see for yourself.

Comment: OK this is AWEsome.  Totally works for the Class case.  Moving the decorator on top of the pass function shows:  AttributeError: 'MyTest' object has no attribute '__name__' with the Passed function with a test_that_passes (__main__.MyTest) ... ERROR statement at the top of the output.

Comment: Oh, you're right - I made a mistake in the decorator.  Please try the updated code.

Comment: Terrific!! This works for both Class and Function calls.  I believe, I understand what you did here and should be able to write a bunch of other decorators that will be useful to my team.